# Making an UIImage from byte string

Tags: arrays, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, nsdata

I am paring a XML and getting an image in Byte form and I have put that in a string. Now I have to draw that image.

I have tried to use various methods but no success. How can I do this?

Comment: Which methods did you try? `[UIImage imageWithData:<#(NSData *)#>]`is a method you tried?

Comment: @ j_freyre --YES i tried but i failed to convert my NSString to NSData

Comment: have you tried storing the Bytes as an NSData, and then using [UIImage alloc] initFromData:]?

Comment: You can convert `NSString` to `NSData` with `[myDataAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the string to NSData:

```
NSString* str= ....
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then take a look at:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used this but that did not show any image to me so itried to use following code...converting UIImage to NSString and then back to image ................But again this is not working ..
UIImage *topImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneFullRes.png"];
 
 NSData* topImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(topImage, 1.0);


 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:topImageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
 imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the byte into NSData and then you can get the image using

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

OR

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```